# Find the co-ordinates of the reflector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, vectors, 3d

Consider two points in 3D given by $A =(0,0,0)$ and $B=(b_x,b_y,b_z)$ given in cartesian form. $A$ is known and B is unknown.

Let's assume If I send a photon from $A$ towards $B$ along a straight line, it takes $x$ seconds for it to reach.

Now, consider I have a reflector at $C =(c_x,c_y,c_z)$.

$\vec{u}$ is the unit vector from A to C. Also,  $\vec{v}$ is the unit vector from B to C. These unit vectors are known to me.

It is given that If I send the photon towards B, it will hit the reflector at $C$ and then reach point $B$ in $x+ 10$ seconds (In effect, it travels along 2 straight line segments AC and CB).

I am trying to compute the coordinates of the reflector, $C$, as well the point $B$  based on this information. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: @peterwhy   I meant B. Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Given the locations of $A,B$, if the unit vectors $\vec u, \vec v$ are not parallel or antiparallel, they should ideally point to a common point $C$. And the timing information is not necessary.

Comment: @peterwhy I see. The timing information is available. But, in my general case, $B$ is unknown.  But, I thought that will lead to too many unknowns. I will edit the question to make $B$ unknown.

Comment: Do you know how to solve it in 2D?

Comment: IN any case, A and B are focal points of an ellipse.

Comment: @Moti I know I can calculate angle ACB from the two unit vectors. Also I can infer that AC + CB = AB + d based on assuming the speed of photon.  But still I don't know how to solve in ,2d or 3d.

Comment: @Moti Also, when I said reflector, I was mostly saying a change in direction from unit vector $u$ to  the unit vector $v$. It may not obey the reflection laws as such. It can be any new direction specified by $v$.

Comment: For any selection of B you can find an ellipse that will provide you the desired result of reflection. Select B and then draw the circle that view the segment AB at the angle defined by the directions of vectors. You get a circle - select any point on the circle and calculate the ellipse going through this point with A, B focals.