# Find the co-ordinates of a 3D triangle $ABC$ given 2 unit vectors, a side and a property

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, triangles, 3d

There is a triangle $ABC$ in 3D space.  I am given the following:

1. $\vec{u}_{AC}:$ The unit vector along the direction of $AC$.
2. $\vec{u}_{BC}:$ The unit vector along the direction of $BC$.
3. point $A$ is $(0,0,0)$.
4. $AC+ BC = AB + k$, where $k$ is known.

**My aim is to locate points $B$ and $C$.**

It seems to me that there is enough information to identify co-ordinates of $B$ and $C$. Do you agree? If yes, how exactly can I proceed to find those co-ordinates?

> My attempt: I can use dot product between $\vec{u}_{AC}$ and  $\vec{u}_{BC}$ to identify $<ACB$. But, how do I proceed further. I am not sure.

Comment: To @wanderer: If $\vec{u}_{AC}$ is given, then you have its components, right?

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can rotate the points to make them planar to the _xy_ plane, and also have for example $\vec{u}_{BC}$ along the _x_ axis. This will turn the problem into one with three unknowns, the two _x_ components of $AB$ and $AC$ and the _y_ component of $B$ or $C$. But you only have one equation, so the problem isn't solvable as such.

Comment: Related to [Find the co-ordinates of the reflector](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4819013/89922)?

Comment: @peterwhy Yes. But I thought this interpretation is much simpler to solve for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the last equation of

$$ \| C - A \| + \| B-C \| = \| B- A \| +  k $$

but with $A=(0,0,0)$, the above is

$$ \| C  \| + \| B-C \| = \| B \| +  k $$

We can freely rotate our coordinate system around it will not change the nature of the problem, and so I chose a system where $B_y=C_y = y$, yielding

$$ \sqrt{C_x^2+y^2} + (B_x-C_x) = \sqrt{B_x^2+y^2} + k $$

which has three unknowns, $y$, $B_x$ and $B_y$. So there is information missing to solve this geometry.

If you make assumptions about $B_x$ and $C_x$ then you can use the above to set

$$ y^2 = \frac{ k (2 C_x + k) (2 B_x -k) (2 B_x -2 C_x-k)}{4 ( B_x-C_x-k)^2 }$$

Once you solve the 2D planar triangle (if you can), then use the lengths of the sides and the direction vectors to get the 3D coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: I think I understand it now. U r saying, bring the 3D triangle to XY plane and rotate it such that y coordinate of B and C become the same. Now, compute the lengths of the sides. Then length info along with unit vector info can help me identify the 3D triangle coordinates

Comment: Then, I guess, if I know the coordinates of B in addition, I only have one unknown and this can be solved using the one equation, right?

Comment: @wanderer - yes, if you know $B_x$ and $y=B_y$ then you would be left with $C_x$ to solve for.